# How can I create a Webmin Cluster?

Tags: server, cluster-computing, clustered-index, webmin, virtualmin

I want to install packages all over servers at the same time. Finally I will install a cloud service and distributed filesystem for testing purposes?

I found Webmin has Cluster option, but no clue or clear documentation about how to do. Webmin UI is useful for me, I decided to use it whenever I need inventory of any of servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the modules in the **Cluster** category make use of the **Webmin Servers Index** module and RPC to control other systems.

*Webmin* has great [cluster documentation](https://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Cluster_Webmin_Servers). There is cluster option at navigation menu, just start from looking around and reading manual. It will be clearer for you then.

Comment: But documentation does not provide parameters, so I tried every possibility. Finally created a cluster. Cluster shell are easy to run a command over all nodes. Thanks.